# Allowing multiple users to decrypt pgp emails for one email-address

Tags: email, encryption, gpg

me and my business partner each have our own company email address for which we use PGP. This allows us to communicate safely with our customers. However in order to communicate securely, the sender already has to know our personal email addresses. We also have a mail@ email address that is forwarded to both our accounts where most of new customers contact us.

I was now wondering if it is possible to somehow create a master key for that email address and give each of us our own subkey which can be used for decryption.
I am aware, that I could simply create one key for the email address and copy it to both our machines. While this scenario would be fine as long as it is just the two of us, I am thinking ahead to when we possibly have an employee that should also be able to decrypt mails for this email address. If the employee would leave our company again, I would like to be able to simple revoke his sub-key and be done with it instead of either trusting the employee to delete the key on his system or creating a new key each time.

I would imagine that many problems arise from this setup like:

- Would the sender need to encrypt the message for each subkey?

  - If so, the sender would always need to recheck the keyserver before encryption

    - Also we would depend on the sender to only encrypt for non-revoked keys, so security would not be on our side.
  - If not, the subkeys would be able to decrypt the main key's data. How could one prohibit this for revoked keys.

All in all, it seems that my scenario is unlikely to be solved easily by GPG, but maybe someone has some clever idea to solve the problem?

Another solution to the problem could be a mail-server side script that checks incoming mail for the mail@ address and re-encrypts GPG encrypted mails with a given set of personal keys before the mail is forwarded. What do you think about that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting to do fundamentally isn't the way GPG works.

Let's say that something like this existed: you could distribute one public key that could be decrypted by multiple private keys.  When the sender encrypts the message with the public key, it would then be decryptable by anyone with any of those private keys.  Now you want to revoke one of the private keys.  But decryption doesn't go through a third party; anyone who has a matching private key can decrypt the message.  The only way to revoke a key is to let the sender know to use a different public key.  Which is the same thing you'd do if there were only one private key.

So, ultimately, there's not any particular advantage to having multiple private keys for one public key.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GPG doesn't provide such mechanism. PGP offers ADKs (additional decryption keys) for this purpose, but unfortunately this is a feature outside of the OpenPGP standard (and also patented one) and thus GPG doesn't provide it.